# Filtering with large dataset

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite

I have a large data-set with roughly 10,000 records. I want to be able to have a filter mechanism on this data-set. That basically performs a LIKE sql expression on a field and returns the matching results.

To do this, I've used JQuery to bind the "input" event on my filter textbox to my filter handler function.

The issue at the moment is, that If a load of keys are pressed at once in the textbox, then the filter function gets called many times, thus making many SQL calls to filter which is very inefficient.

Is there a way I can detect in my handler when the user has finished typing or when there's a gap of a certain period and only then performing the filtering? So i only make one database call when loads of characters get input at once. If the characters get input slowly though, I want to be able to filter each time.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of doing it [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VVG8x/1/)

```
var test = 0;

$('body').on('keyup','input',function(){
    var val = $.trim($(this).val());  
    test++;

    if(val !== ""){
      doSomething(test);
    }
});

function doSomething(t){

    setTimeout(function(){
        if(t === test){
           //Place to Call the other Function or just do sql stuff
           alert($.trim($('input').val()));
        }
    },500);
}
```

There is a global variable to test against, if the user typed another letter. And the setTimeout function waits 500ms to see if they did type another letter.

I'm sure there are better ways to do this, but that will probably get you started.